# Adjust navbar minimum height depending on screen width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using bootstrap and have set a minimum height of 150px for the navbar. This works but I want to re-adjust the minimum height to 30px when the screen width is lower than 768px.

I am using the class .navbar-min-height to set the minimum width thus trying to call that class again under @media with the new min-height pixels but the navbar remains the same height of 150px. Anyway I can get around this?

CSS File

```
/* works */
.navbar-min-height{
    min-height: 150px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Not working */
    .navbar-min-height{
        min-height: 30px;
    }
}
```

Html Page

```
<nav class="nav navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-min-height navbar-custom">
    ......
</nav>
```

Comment: It's hard to say without a concrete example, but I might guess that it's because you're using min-height instead of height. The browser will just interpret min-height as a suggestion.

Comment: @veiko Have tried with height and same results.

Comment: It's likely something in the `bootstrop.css` that conflct with your own CSS. Don't forget that you might have more that one `navbar-fixed-top` (including one which might be collapsed at full size) and that you can't go below the default height for the `navbar-fixed-top` without  overwriting the default `bootstrop.css` styles. Also, you might want to make sure that all of your `navbar-fixed-top` elements do not have fixed sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work by using "media all" ?

I don't think this css is wrong, the menu should be 30px from 0 to 768px then 150px

If this doesn't work try setting the size explicitly

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-min-height{
        min-height: 30px;
    }
} 

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-min-height{
        min-height: 150px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put .navbar-min-height inside @media (min-width: 769)

Here is a working example:

```css
@media (min-width: 789px) {
   nav p {
     font-size: 1.5em;
     }
  }

@media (max-width: 788px) {
    nav p {
      font-size: 3em;
     }
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Sit Amet</p>
</nav>
```

Now just run the above snippet, and resize the screen and the font size changes when the screen width goes below 789.

Now if you were to remove the @media min-width then the text would not increase size.

Answer (score 0):

`min-height` as it says, is the minimum, not maximum value. if the `navbar`, has a height of 150, then you may have element within it which force it to have a greater height. check the child elements.

Also, check that the given media-query takes effect, using the inspector.